# How to get xml file over http?

Tags: java, xml, web-services

A xml file with data will be sent over http to server my job is to get that xml file and parse it using web service and I am using Netbeans 6.9. How can i get that xml file can anyone tell me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [To recieve Soap Message over Http using Java Web Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656489/to-recieve-soap-message-over-http-using-java-web-service)

Comment: i'm voting to close this because it seems to be the same question you posted a few days ago. you havn't got any answers to your other questions till now, i've seen that, but shouldn't you consider giving _more_ information about your problem instead of writing it in one confusing sentence? also, a link to your other question with would have been nice (but generally, reposting a question is never a good idea - you'll only get flames from that instead of answers... the best way would have been to edit you old question and try to rephrase it and giving more information about what you've tried)

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this?

```
URL xmlUrl = new URL("http://www.rekindle.co.za/rss.xml");
InputStream in = xmlUrl.openStream();
Document doc = parse(in);
```

Taken from a similar question about parsing at http://www.java-forums.org/xml/22674-get-xml-data-url.html

Comment: but problem is xml file will be generated automatically by another webservice for every 10 mins and sent to server using http. so i can't know xml file name then how can i read it from http port.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to use `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're responsible for writing the service using servlets and the xml file will be POSTed to the server, you can access it using HttpServletRequest.getParameter(paramName).

Comment: tks but can you tell me briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClient for the same to recieve the XML , After recieving the xml use JAXB/XMLbeans parser to parse the xml.
You must have to sure about xml's xsd before parsing the same.
If already you are having xsd against the incoming xml then just created the classes by using using any above mentioned tool.